# Failed login localhost SQL Server after change password expiration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, failed-to-connect

I have databases on my localhost server Microsoft SQL Server 2017, today I got password expiration and have change to a new password. But when I want to connect to the database localhost server it failed to login using the new password. And cannot connect with Windows Authentication too. How can I login to server localhost again?

Comment: See [Recover access to a SQL Server instance](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and [More on Recovering Access to a SQL Server Instance](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4672/more-on-recovering-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Comment: (Also, since this just seems to be a password sync issue and not lack of an account, have you tried restarting SQL Server from services.msc or Configuration Manager?)

Comment: @AaronBertrand ya I have restarting SQL server from services.msc and configuration manager, also restarting my laptop. It still failed login error 233 first, then error: Login failed for user 'existinguser'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Comment: Find the file called `errorlog` on your system (which you can open with a text file) and give us more details about the state and other specifics that go along with the 18456 error message (which is intentionally vague in the connection dialog). And confirm whether this is a SQL auth user, a local machine Windows user (e.g. `WORKSTATION\user` or `YOURMACHINENAME\user`), or a domain account (e.g. `CORPDOMAIN\user`).

Comment: @AaronBertrand A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)

Comment: Try forcing TCP by using `TCP:127.0.0.1` in the connection dialog? (You may have to enable the TCP/IP protocol in Configuration Manager.)

Comment: Still failed login ussing TCP 127.0.0.1, meanwhile TCP/IP protocol in configuration manager have enabled. Can I change my password again if I have master.mdf file? But it seems that the sql server password changer application is not free :( @AaronBertrand

Comment: I have no idea what a `password changer application` is but did you try the approaches in the first two links I offered? Those should let you log in and reset the password for any SQL account (including `sa`), but I'm not sure I have the ability to help diagnose exactly what might be going on with any domain accounts. Sometimes it is easier to just install a new instance, make sure you enable both Windows and SQL auth, add yourself as administrator during setup, write down the sa password you create, and create a backup SQL auth / sysadmin account or two so you can survive a password change.